# ASP.NET Web Pages Administration page

Tags: asp.net, iis, tfs

I'm not sure if it's the best place to ask this question. But it's conсerned aspютуе and iis and so i'll ask it.

I have web application hosted in iis (really it's tfs which i try to get up). Main page is normally opened with my windows credentials but if i go to admin page "server_name/tfs/_Admin" (to create project in project collection) I redirected to "server_name/tfs/_Admin/Login.cshtml?ReturnUrl=~%2f_admin" and get strange page (see screen).

What is the page and where is it in filesystem or why is it shown?
[image]

Comment: Which version of TFS do you use? Have you specified the site port correctly (default 8080)? have you ever modified the TFS site structure, edit the site etc? If you never changed the site before, please try to clean caches on both client and App tier server, then try it again. If that still not work, you can try to repair the TFS, then try it again.

Comment: I got the copy of whole server where tfs is installed. The target is to try to upgrade 2015.4 to 2017. But before manipulations i decided to make me sure that the current instance normally works. And i encountered this problem. Well, i'll try your advices today. Thanks.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue? any update?

Comment: No, i tried all the ways you proposed, but page is kept wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the TFS site was messed by something that which escaped our monitoring. Seems it redirected to other site page.

You can try to back current TFS site files first ,then copy the site files from another normal machine which installed the same version of TFS, then overwrite current site files. Then try it again.

If that still not work, I'm afraid that you have to uninstall and reinstall the TFS to fix that.

In you case, I suggest you to [Move or Clone Team Foundation Server from one hardware to another](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/move-clone-hardware) then [upgrade the new server to 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/upgrade/get-started).

Comment: Thank you for your advices! Currently admins deploy new pure server with tfs 2015 and after it'll be deployed i'll continue to try upgrading it to tfs 2017.